# How to loop through all members and their Roles in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    async def interest(self):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(779743465252192297)
        em = discord.Embed(title ="Interest By time : ",color = discord.Colour.random())
        total = 0 
        for members in discord.Guild.members:
            try:
                em.add_field(name = "Member Name: ",value = members.name)
                for keys,values in role.items():
                    if keys in members.roles.name:
                        em.add_field(name=f"{keys} : " ,value = values)
                        total += values
                em.add_field(name = "Total : " ,value = total )
                em.set_footer(text = "Type `.role_shop` to See how you can spend Money",icon_url=channel.guild.owner.avatar_url)
                
                await members.send(embed = em)
            except:
                pass
```

This is my code and I want to loop through all members and then through their roles and add a value to the var total.
This is my role Dict :`role = {"Coder":100,"Gamer":100,"Anime Weeb":100,"Superior Coder":150,"Mods":100,"Partners":50,"Owner":999999}`

The error which I am receiving is : `File "d:\bot1\fold\onevent.py", line 33, in interest for members in discord.Guild.members: TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable`

Plz provide a way through which I can perform my Task

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `discord.Guild.members` directly. You need an instance of `discord.Guild` object. You can get this by using [`client.get_guild(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild). Also, `member.roles` returns a list. So you cannot use `member.roles.name`. You have to loop through the roles too or you can do it on one line for loop but you must change your code a bit to have a more optimized code.

```py
async def interest(self):
    roles = {"Coder": 100, "Gamer": 100, "Anime Weeb": 100, "Superior Coder": 150, "Mods": 100, "Partners": 50,
            "Owner": 999999}
    channel = self.client.get_channel(779743465252192297)
    guild = self.client.get_guild(<guild id>)
    em = discord.Embed(title="Interest By time : ", color=discord.Colour.random())
    total = 0
    for members in guild.members:
        try:
            em.add_field(name="Member Name: ", value=members.name)
            for role in [role for role in members.roles if role.name in roles.keys()]:
                em.add_field(name=f"{role} : ", value=roles[role])
                total += roles[role]
            em.add_field(name="Total : ", value=total)
            em.set_footer(text="Type `.role_shop` to See how you can spend Money",
                          icon_url=channel.guild.owner.avatar_url)

            await members.send(embed=em)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: File "d:\bot1\fold\onevent.py", line 33, in interest
    for members in guild.members:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'
@Nurqm

Comment: Have you defined intents and typed your actual guild id in the`self.client.get_guild`?

Comment: yea I Have,
My intents -  `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">", intents=discord.Intents.all(),case_insensitive = True,help = None)`  
and 
My channel ID inside - ```guild = self.client.get_guild(779743465252192297)```

Comment: There's no reason you to get this error unless your guild id is wrong. Are you sure it's true?

Comment: we can get the guild ID by right-clicking on the server name(while being in developer mode) 
I did the same @Nurqm